# Send C code from textbox to server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC framework.
In my view, i have a textbox which will contain C code. I want to send this code to the controller. My code in the view is like:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="8" style="margin-top: 5px;" id="code">

</textarea> 

$.ajax({
         url: "/Contest/SubmitContestProblem",
         type: "POST",
         data: { code: $("#code").val() }
      })
        .done(function (data) {

         })
        .fail(function () {

         })
        .always(function () {

        });
```

My controller code looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitContestProblem(string code)
{
     return View();
}
```

I would like to know whether I have to follow any specific encoding for sending the code of the textbox to controller or not.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I have not used any encoding. When I make the ajax call, it gives me the following error : 

" POST http://localhost:60946/Contest/SubmitContestProblem 500 (Internal Server Error) "

Comment: And...? Try logging your errors (http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs) and/or watching what the server's doing (http://getglimpse.com/).

Comment: `JsonResult` is the wrong return type if you are using a `View`.  Use an `ActionResult`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#button").click(function () {
        var code = $('#code').val();
        $.getJSON("/Contest/SubmitContestProblem", { id: code}, function (myData) {

         }))
         $.each(myData, function (index, itemData) {

         }));
      });

     public JsonResult SubmitContestProblem(string code)
     {
        return View();
     }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done and how it answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

This is where the [`FromBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute.aspx) attribute comes in... but it can be a little tricky to use.

Change your controller method to read:

```
public JsonResult SubmitContestProblem([FromBody]string code)
{
    return View();
}
```

This will tell the `Controller` support code to parse the body of the request into the `code` parameter.  Unfortunately the *parse* is not just a copy, it requires that the body of the request be prefixed with an equals character `=`.  You can achieve this with an AJAX `POST` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Contest/SubmitContestProblem",
    type: "POST",
    data: "=" + $("#code").val()
})
```

When you `POST` with text in the `data` option the text is directly sent as the body of the request.  Adding the `=` at the start lets the Controller correctly parse the request body, strip the `=` from the start of it and put the rest into your `code` parameter.

And no, it doesn't make sense.  It's just the way it is.